# MySql Convert Date from STR_TO_DATE date_format

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, sql-date-functions

How do you convert the following date Mar 7 2017 1:26:46:886AM to 2017-03-07 01:26:00

```
select DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('Mar 7 2017 1:26:46:886AM', '%b-%d-%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');
```

I keep getting null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE("Mar 7 2017 1:26:46:886AM", "%M %d %Y %H:%i:%S")
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use

```
select STR_TO_DATE('Mar 7 2017 1:26:46:886AM', '%b %d %Y %h:%i:%s%f' )
```